# iPhone - Differentiate UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, sleep, multitasking

When registering the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, I notice that this notification is not triggered when the device enters in sleep mode.

But, when waking it up, the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification notification is triggered. It is also triggered when coming back from background mode.

So how can I know if my application comes back from background mode, or is activated following a wake up of the device ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those don't balance each other; they are posted for unrelated events. I believe you want `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` when detecting your app coming back from the background, and `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` when detecting certain other situations (including sleep.)

Note that `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` also shows for events such as "incoming phone call was ignored" and "the operating system displayed an alert that is not part of your process" (e.g. a text message.)

Comment: well that doesn't really work, both are triggered when coming back from background.

Comment: When my phone is in sleep mode, it still receive drawRect updates, that leads to useless actions and battery use. How would you deal with that ?

Comment: Yes, you do see both on return from the background, but you only see the `Background` and `Foreground` notifications for multitasking.

Comment: And you don't see `-drawRect:` updates when the phone is asleep. The phone doesn't turn off immediately when you press the Sleep button. When the phone actually goes to sleep, your app does stop running.